# Is the space $C[0,1]$ locally compact?

Tags: functional-analysis, convergence-divergence

Let $C[0,1]$ be the space of continuous functions, equipped with the $\sup$-norm.

My question is, how one can prove, that this space is not locally compact? Is it possible to show this explicitly, by providing a sequence of continuous functions, which does not contain a convergent subsequence?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the intervals $E_n=[1/n,1/(n+1)]$, $n\in\mathbb N$. Define continuous functions $f_n$ such that $f_n=0$ outside $E_n$, and $f_n=1$ on the mid point of $E_n$.

Then $\|f_n\|_\infty=1$ for all $n\in\mathbb N$, and $\|f_n-f_m\|_\infty=1$ whenever $n\ne m$, so the sequence admits no convergent subsequence.

Answer (score 2):

Try $f_n(x):=x^n$.

The deeper reason is that $C[0,1]$ is infinite dimensional, so by Riesz theorem its unit ball is not compact.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to show something even more amazing: Any locally compact Hausdorff real or complex topological vector space is finite dimensional and every finite dimensional Hausdorff topological vector space has the usual topology. See [Terry Tao's blog](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2011/05/24/locally-compact-topological-vector-spaces/) for proofs.