# Is $C([0,1])$ a compact space?

Tags: compactness, topological-vector-spaces

Is $C([0,1])$ (I guesss with the max-norm) a compact space?

I have to know that because I want to apply Arzela Ascoli.

Comment: It is a real vector space...

Comment: If it were, then so would be the subspace of constant functions, which is isometric (hence homeomorphic) to $\mathbb{R}$ (usual norm, non compact).

Comment: It’s not even locally compact; see [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/244510/is-the-space-c0-1-locally-compact?rq=1).

Comment: The subspace of functions $[0,1] \to [0,1]$ where $|f(x)-f(y)| \leq |x-y|$ is compact, that follows from Arzela-Ascoli.

Comment: @scevvc: your set is unbounded, you need to assume a tiny bit more.

Comment: @GEdgar, julien $[0,1] \to [0,1]$, not $\mathbb R$.

Comment: @sdcvvc This is not a subspace, then.

Comment: I guess "subspace" in the sense used in topology...

Comment: @GEdgar Yes, probably. Confusing terminology...

Comment: @QiaochuYuan If you don't mind me asking, what is the significance of it being a real vector space?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider $f_n(x) = \begin{cases} 0 & x \in [0,\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{n}) \\
1+n(x-\frac{1}{2}) & x \in [\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{n}, \frac{1}{2}) \\
1 & x\in [\frac{1}{2},1] \end{cases}$.

(Since you were considering Arzela Ascoli.)

Comment: That's a lot of work when you could consider $f_n(x)=n$.

Comment: I realize that, but the $f_n$ are bounded, which shows that it goes beyond considering constant functions, and it is easy to see that the $f_n$ are not equicontinuous, so it is really not a lot of work at all.

Answer (score 12):

No, of course not. No (nontrivial) normed space is compact. The sets $\{v\mid\|v\|<n\}$ form an open cover with no finite subcover.

Answer (score 2):

No it is not, but you don't need $\rm C([0,1])$ to be compact to apply Ascoli-Arzela, but that $[0,1]$ is compact !