# Show that $f$ is uniformly continuous - Compactness

Tags: real-analysis, compactness, uniform-continuity

> Let $K := \{x \in C[0,1] : x(0) \in [-3,4], |x(t)-x(s)| \leq d
>  |t^2-s^2|, \forall t,s \in C[0,1]\}$. Let $y \in C[0,1]$ and $f : K
>  \to \mathbb{R}$ defined as $f(x)= \int_0^1 x(t)y(t)dt$. Show that $f$
>   is uniformly continuous.

**Partial proof :**

1. $f(x)= \int_0^1 x(t)y(t)dt$ is a dot product, noted $<x,y>$.
2. $||f||_2 = \sqrt{<x,y>}$ is a continuous function.
3. $g \circ ||f||_2$ is a continuous function, where $g : \mathbb{R}
       \to \mathbb{R}$ difined as $g(x)= x^2$
4. $C[0,1]$ is compact

Thus it is sufficient to show that $K$ is closed (well-known theorem).

Is it hard to show that $K$ is closed? Am I on the good way? Is there a simpler way to proof this problem?

**Edit :**

> **Theorem :** Let ${x_n}$ a sequence in $C[0,1]$ such that
>
> - for all $t \in [0,1]$, the sequence ${x_n(t)}$ is bound over $\mathbb{R}$
> - the set ${x_n : n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is equicontinuous.
>
> Then there exists a subsequence $\{x_{n_k}\}$ uniformly convergent.

The teacher of the course left a theorem seen in a previous course, is that this theorem can be helpful in this question?

Comment: Well, sorry to see that you deleted an identical copy of this question and then asked again. I was nearly done with a rather thorough answer when your last question was deleted. Not really keen on writing it up again.

Comment: @Dan I sincerely apologize; I wouldn't do it again!

Comment: No sweat, just good to bear in mind others might be mid-response! `:)` In short, your approach can work fine (although there are other ways to see this as well). Show that $K$ is sequentially closed, which is to say that the limit $x$ in $C[0,1]$ of a uniformly Cauchy sequence $\{x_n\}$ in $K$ is itself in $K$. This can be done directly.

Comment: @Dan We don't see theory about uniformly Cauchy sequence, so I can't use it in my proof.

Comment: Then what topology is defined on $C[0,1]$? A uniformly Cauchy sequence is just a sequence that is Cauchy with respect to the usual sup-norm $\|-\|_\infty$ on $C[0,1]$.

Comment: The topology is defined with $|| \cdot ||_{\infty}$

Comment: Ok then you can use the notion of a uniformly Cauchy sequence, just without the name itself. (Assuming you've seen Cauchy sequences at this point.) I've also added a hint towards a much more straightforward solution below.

Comment: Is C[0,1] the space of continuous functions from [0,1] to R? If so,it is certainly not compact.

Comment: @user254665 Yes, you are absolutely right! http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/304352/is-c0-1-a-compact-space

Comment: C[0,1] is an infinite-dimensional normed vector space so it is not even locally compact.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** This is an alternative to your approach that's more straightforward. For all $x \in C[0,1]$ (hence, for all $x \in K$)
$$
|f(x)| \leq \|x\|_\infty\|y\|_\infty.
$$
(Why? Show this if you don't have a theorem that proves this already.) Hence 
$$
\|x_n\|_\infty \to 0\text{ as }n \to \infty \implies |f(x_n)| \to 0\text{ as }n\to\infty,
$$ as well.

Comment: How do you prove that $|f(x)| \leq \|x\|_\infty\|y\|_\infty$? I know you probably use Cauchy-Schwarz, but not the further steps.

Comment: In general, if $z$ is a bounded function on the interval $[a,b]$ then $|\int_a^b z(t)\,dt| \leq \int_a^b |z(t)|\,dt \leq (b-a)\sup_{t \in [a,b]}|z(t)|$. The first inequality follows from the triangle inequality (and the definition of the integral in the leftmost expression as a limit of Riemann sums). The second inequality can again be proved using Riemann sums, noting $|z(s)| \leq \sup_{t \in [a,b]}|z(t)|$ for any particular $s \in [a,b]$. Use these facts and properties of the sup-norm to reach the desired conclusion.